# Alternative to og metadata (facebook share)?

Tags: php, html, facebook, metadata

I'm using an MVC framework to generate pages in PHP. I'm using a static header and footer with a body that is generated on the fly.

I've set the metadata up in the head of my template, but I want the share icon to display a specific image for each page (each page will have its own image, description and title), as every page uses the same header, is there an alternate way to supply the links?

My setup at the moment is too generic:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="<?php echo base_url();?>"/>
<meta property="og:type"               content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="CritMyWork" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="CritMyWork is an application that allows creators to share their work and recieve feedback from peers." />
<meta property="og:image"              content="<?php echo base_url()."application/img/fb-share-icon.jpg"?>"/>
```

Comment: You can only specify those values “at runtime”, when you use the Feed dialog for sharing, or make the post via API. That of course won’t help in case users share the URL by themselves, by simply inputting it on Facebook. If you are using an MVC framework already, then you should make the header “dynamic” as well, so that you can output the relevant meta data for each page in there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this... If you have a base controller in your MVC framework, define a class variable like this:

`somewhere in class BaseController`:
`public $fb_share_image = 'fb-share-icon.jpg'`

then in other controllers, just change the value, like:

`somewhere in class OtherController extends BaseController`:
`public $fb_share_image = 'fb-share-icon2.jpg'`

Then the last line of your header snippet becomes:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url()."application/img/".$fb_share_image ?>"/>
```